# How to merge untracked code into master on github?

Tags: git, github

Last year, I uploaded a version of my project into my github repository. I haven't been able to work on the code for quite a while and now that I'm coming back to it, I've discovered that my local version is substantially further along than the version on github.

Oddly, enough, I must not have been properly tracking changes since that last repository update, because git doesn't seem to exist locally for the project.

So how can I clean this mess up? How do I merge all the updated local files into the master without either overwriting the local files or making a complete mess of the files on github?

Can I even connect my local files to github without the github version overwriting the local set?

Any and all advice appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Sure David, you can create a new branch in your development area, or your repository. This will keep things safe on either end. You can then safely merge things in whichever way you choose best, whenever you're ready. In your new branch you could push to github, without overwriting your local set, e.g. Since things are pretty open ended it seems, I'll leave it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your local project doesn't seem to even be a Git repository, this is probably the most straightforward way to get those changes merged with what you've got on GitHub:

- Clone the GitHub repository into a new directory
- Copy your changed local files into the cloned repository

  - In the simplest case, `cp -R local_dir/* cloned_dir/`, or you can move things piecemeal
- Commit the files that are now changed in the cloned repository

As you commit, you can arrange things in branches and multiple commits any way you'd like. `git add -p` is helpful if you only want to stage part of a file.